# Lattice Paths with moves $(1, 0)$, $(1, 1)$, and $(1, -1)$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Find a closed formula for the generating function that counts the number of lattice paths from $(0, 0)$ to $(n, 0)$ which never dip below $y=0$ and consist of the moves $(1, 0)$, $(1, 1)$, and $(1, -1)$.

---

I have been stuck trying to solve this problem and I am not making any progress.

I would prefer hints and outlines about how to solve this problem, rather then a complete solution.

My idea so far is to sum over the possible number of $(1,0)$ moves. Removing these $i (1,0)$ moves would create a situation similar to Dyck paths of length $n-i$ counted by the $(n-i)/2$th Catalan number. The $i (1,0)$ moves can be reinserted in $\binom ni$ ways. However, this results in a formula where the index $i$ must be the same parity as $n$ and I do not know how to continue this idea to a generating function in closed form.

Comment: Not sure this will work easily, but I would try to work out some recurrence relation for such a sequence, based on the last step?

Comment: Compute the first 8 or 10 terms, and search the OEIS.  I'm pretty sure you'll find it.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MotzkinNumber.html

Comment: couldn't you apply $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n}{n-i} = \binom{n}{2j}$?

Comment: That should be $1,1,2,4,9, 21, 51$.  You want [OEIS sequence A001006](https://oeis.org/A001006).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall how the generating function for Catalan paths is derived. You look at the first time the path returns to zero. This uniquely factorizes $C_{n}$ as $(\nearrow, C_k,\searrow, C_{n-1-k})$ for some $k$ between $0$ and $n-1$, so that
$$
C_n=\sum_k C_kC_{n-1-k}\text{ for }n\ge 1,C_0=1\implies C(x)=1+xC(x)^2
$$
Now let us try to do the same thing with your paths. Let $M_n$ denote the set of paths to $(n,0)$. We *almost* still have the factorization 
$$
M_n\stackrel{?}=\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-2}(\nearrow, M_k,\searrow, M_{n-2-k})
$$
by looking at the first time the path returns to zero. However, this only accounts for paths which start with a $\nearrow$. What remains are paths which start with a horizontal step. But in that case, what follows is a legal path of length $n-1$. Therefore, the actual equation is
$$
M_n=\;\;(\to, M_{n-1})\;\;+\;\;\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-2}(\nearrow ,M_k,\searrow, M_{n-2-k})
$$

Combined with the base case $M_0=1$, this translates to the generating function equation
$$
M(x) = 1+xM(x)+x^2M(x)^2.
$$